# Replace chunks of HTML with double quotes using SUBSTITUTE

Tags: google-sheets

I want to replace the following chunks of html contained in a cell:

**Original**

```
<table class="generic">
```

**Replacement**

```
<table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
```

**Original**

```
<h2>Especificaciones</h2> <p></p>
```

**Replacement**

*Nothing - delete this chunk of html code*

This is what I´ve got so far:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(Results_ES!K5, "<h2>Especificaciones</h2> <p></p>", "")
```

...but I don´t know how to substitute the other chunk because it has double quotes.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(Results_ES!K5, "<h2>Especificaciones</h2> <p></p>", "", "<table class="generic">", "<table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">")
```

I read that I could use CHAR(34) to escape double quotes but I don´t know how to use it in this context.

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation operator `&`, for example:

```
"<table class=" & CHAR(34) & "generic" & CHAR(34) & ">"
```

Or, the `CONCATENATE` function:

```
CONCATENATE("<table class=",CHAR(34),"generic",CHAR(34),">")
```

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(Results_ES!K5, "<h2>Especificaciones</h2> <p></p>", "", "<table class=" & CHAR(34) & "generic" & CHAR(34) & ">", "<table class=" & CHAR(34) & "data-table" & CHAR(34) &  "id=" & CHAR(34) & "product-attribute-specs-table" & CHAR(34) & ">")`

Comment: But Google Sheets says: **Error** Wrong number of arguments to SUBSTITUTE. Expected between 3 and 4 arguments, but got 5 arguments.

Comment: You can't replace _both_ strings in a single function call, you will need to _nest_ two calls to the `SUBSTITUTE` function. ie. `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Results_ES!K5, ....`

Answer (score 2):

For the record, this is what I've done:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Results_ES!K5, "<h2>Especificaciones</h2> <p></p>", ""), "<table class=" & CHAR(34) & "generic" & CHAR(34) & ">", "<table class=" & CHAR(34) & "data-table" & CHAR(34) & " id=" & CHAR(34) & "product-attribute-specs-table" & CHAR(34) & ">")
```